# angularjs and ng-bind-html not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ngsanitize

I use angularjs with ng-bind-html and it works. But my html string looks like this:

```
<p>Hello <span style="font-size:40px;">World</span></p>
```

I would expect in the result, that World is bigger then Hello. But Hello and World has the same size!

Why that? Is this a problem from ngSanitize, or what can I do, that I get the right font-size?

regards

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30995775/2435473) out, it should work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<p>Hello <span style="font-size:40px !important;">World</span></p>
```

With `!important` you can force your style to apply...

Comment: This is not working! It's looks like that ngSanitize ignore the style property.

Comment: Have you tried to append your style as a css class?

Comment: No, the problem is, that this html string is from user content. The user make this format! So I can't work with css classes and !important...

Comment: Have you included `ngSanitize`?

Comment: yes, otherwise the html string would not showed in the app... With this link you can play arround http://plnkr.co/edit/pPHzdCbkflyj7DTRt8aJ?p=preview . Change in the script.js <a href="#">links!</a> to <a style="font-size:40px!important!" href="#">links!</a>.... So links! should be bigger, but is not!

Comment: Thank you, you have to trust your HTML like it is described in [`angularjs docs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml): http://plnkr.co/edit/4DWBXEqMXkORwf3YrH59?p=preview

Comment: You are welcome. But you should also look at the proposal from Pankaj Parker in your comment, which provides a nice solution with filter!

Comment: But this trust can't handle à &agrave;